# if statement not working on new server, requires use of "empty"

Tags: php, session-variables

I've inherited some code that is working great on one server, which is running PHP 7.1.7.  Throughout the code their are numerous if statements similar to the following that are checking to see if a variable exists.

```
if ($_SESSION['user'])

if ($_POST['company_id'])
```

On the new server, which as PHP 7.2.5, these if statements are throwing errors.  I'm having to change them all to use "empty".

```
if (empty($_SESSION['user']))

if (!empty($_POST['company_id']))
```

This wouldn't be a big deal if there were only a few, but there's 100+.  I've tried changing the PHP version to 7.1.7 on the new server to match the old, but still have the same issue.

I have to imagine there is a setting somewhere that could be changed to allow these work without the need to use "empty" on all of them.  Thanks for any insight.

Comment: please post the errormessage - maybe "just" a notice - [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: One server is probably defaulted to show all notices, which the other was squelching them (which squelching them led that prior developer to be utterly lazy in their coding).

Answer (score 0):

Like @IncredibleHat suggested, you can prevent this by suppressing error notices. Any one of these three should address the warnings.

```
// this can go in your PHP
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);

// OR you can put this in your .htaccess file
php_value error_reporting E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED

// OR you can put this in your php.ini file
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: The best solution though, is to grin n bear it, and pour through the lines of code cleaning up the mess ;)

Comment: Yes, your best solution is to change `if ($_SESSION['user'])` to `if (!empty($_SESSION['user']))`, etc, etc